# How to get RadioButton to play music

Tags: java, android

So I have a class that will play some songs via the MediaPlayer.  I have the following code that When a Radiobutton is selected should play a song, However this does not work, could anyone tell me why?

I do not get any errors, the music just does not play.

Code from the OnCheckedChange Method:

```
        break;          
    case R.id.rFolk1: //setting up sub radiogroup buttons
        if(fsong1.isPlaying() == false)
            fsong1.start();
        break;
    case R.id.rFolk2: //setting up sub radiogroup buttons
        if(fsong2.isPlaying() == false)
            fsong2.start();
        break;
```

Other code for the songs:

```
    fsong1 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.folk1);
    fsong2 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.folk2);
```

Fullcode:

```
public class Music extends Activity implements OnCheckedChangeListener, OnClickListener{

Button playpause;
RadioGroup selectionList, Folk, Rock, Pop, NewWave, Pipe;//define the radiogroup
RadioButton folk1, folk2, rock1, rock2, pop1, pop2, newwave1, newwave2, pipe1, pipe2; //define radiobuttons
MediaPlayer fsong1, fsong2, rsong1, rsong2, psong1, psong2, nwsong1, nwsong2, pisong1, pisong2;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //set fullscreen
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE); 
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN );

    setContentView(R.layout.music); //set layout

    initialize(); //call this method
}

public void initialize(){
    // set up the radiogroups
    selectionList = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.rgMusic);
    Folk = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.rgFolk);
    Rock = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.rgRock);
    Pop = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.rgPop);
    Pipe = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.rgPipe);

    folk1 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.rFolk1);
    folk2 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.rFolk2);
    rock1 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.rRock1);
    rock2 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.rRock2);
    pipe1 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.rPipe1);
    pipe2 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.rPipe2);
    pop1 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.rPop1);
    pop2 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.rPop2);
    newwave1 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.rNewWave1);
    newwave2 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.rNewWave2);

    NewWave = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.rgNewWave);

  //settting up on check changed
    selectionList.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);

    playpause = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bPlayPause);
    playpause.setOnClickListener(this);

    fsong1 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.folk1);
    fsong2 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.folk2);


}

@Override
public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup arg0, int arg1) {
    //case statement for onCheckChange to open a new class/layout
    //
    //This also hides radiogroups and shows others
    switch(arg1){
    case R.id.rFolk:
        Folk.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); //shows rg for folk
        //hides all the rest of the radiogroups if visible
            if(Pipe.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE){
                Pipe.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            if(Rock.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE){
            Rock.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            if(Pop.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE){
            Pop.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            if(NewWave.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE){
            NewWave.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }

        break;
    case R.id.rPipe:
        Pipe.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);//shows rg for pipe
        //hides all the rest of the radiogroups if visible
        if(Folk.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE){
            Folk.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        if(Rock.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE){
        Rock.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        if(Pop.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE){
        Pop.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        if(NewWave.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE){
        NewWave.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }

        break;
    case R.id.rRock:
        Rock.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);//shows rg for rock
        //hides all the rest of the radiogroups if visible
        if(Folk.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE){
            Folk.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        if(Pipe.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE){
        Pipe.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        if(Pop.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE){
        Pop.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        if(NewWave.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE){
        NewWave.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }

        break;
    case R.id.rPop:
        Pop.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);//shows rg for pop
        //hides all the rest of the radiogroups if visible
        if(Folk.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE){
            Folk.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        if(Pipe.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE){
        Pipe.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        if(Rock.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE){
        Rock.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        if(NewWave.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE){
        NewWave.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }

        break;
    case R.id.rNewWave:
        NewWave.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);//shows rg for newwave
        //hides all the rest of the radiogroups if visible
        if(Folk.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE){
            Folk.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        if(Pipe.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE){
        Pipe.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        if(Rock.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE){
        Rock.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        if(Pop.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE){
        Pop.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }

        break;          
    case R.id.rFolk1: //setting up sub radiogroup buttons
        if(fsong1.isPlaying() == false){
            fsong1.start();
        }
        break;
    case R.id.rFolk2: //setting up sub radiogroup buttons
        if(fsong2.isPlaying() == false){
            fsong2.start();
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    // setting the onclick listener for the buttons for play/pause stop

    // check for already playing
    if(fsong1.isPlaying()){

            fsong1.pause();
            // Changing button image to play button
            playpause.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.play_button);

    }else{
        // Resume song
            fsong1.start();
            // Changing button image to pause button
            playpause.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.pause_button);
    }   

}
```

}

Comment: Is that code being called?  If you set a breakpoint does it get hit?

Comment: First make sure OnCheckedChange is fired or not by placing logs on RedioButton selection change

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK I added a Toast in for the section shown above and it seems that It is not making it to this part of the code, however it is running the OnCheckChange above the part shown.

Comment: @Thomas : post ur full code

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK I have edited my above post to include the code

Comment: Could you please include the layout xml file as well?

Answer (score 0):

[I'd advise against creating so many `MediaPlayer`s](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#MediaPlayer%28%29) . They may very well be the cause of your troubles: When you instance too many of them they don't work well.

And you should take a look at the [lifecycle of MediaPlayer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#StateDiagram) as well.

In it you'll find one way to remove your multiple instances of MediaPlayers. You could, for instance change your playing to:

```
  Boolean fsong1, fsong2, rsong1, rsong2, psong1, psong2, nwsong1, nwsong2, pisong1, pisong2;
  Boolean isPlaying=false;
```

//lots of more code

```
  case R.id.rFolk1: //setting up sub radiogroup buttons
    if ((isPlaying) && !fsong1){
        mediaPlayer.stop();
        mediaPlayer.release();
        mediaPlayer = null;
    }
    if (!fsong1){
       //reset all other types of songs!
       fsong1=true;
       isPlaying = true;          
       mediaPlayer=MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.folk1);
       mediaPlayer.start();
    }

    break;
```

Warning: I'm not giving you the whole change you'd have to apply!

Comment: I have never used the .prepare and it always works, And I know that I should not use that many mediaplayers but I am new to android about a week old and I have no idea how else to do it.

Comment: You're right about .prepare. It's needed in other cases, but when you use MediaPlayer.create you don't need to use it.

Comment: It might once I try it, I accidently deleted my layout so I need to remake it

Comment: Ok. Good luck with that. (and don't forget to mark my answer as correct if it helps you ;) )